# Add Data After Adding Table Rows Dynamically Into Table with PHP

Tags: php

Kindly can anyone help per below concept.
I need to post data into a table after successful  adding dynamic table row
Below pages is working fine but when i try to post those data into table am getting error message on results5.php line 11 error:Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

resultskati.php

```
<head>
<script>
function addRows()
{
    var a_name=document.form1.a_name.value;
    var a_in=document.form1.a_in.value;

var tbl = document.getElementById('t');
              var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
              var iteration = lastRow;
              var row = tbl.insertRow(lastRow);           
             var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
             var e1 = document.createElement('input');
             s=lastRow+1;
             e1.type = 'text';
             e1.size=1;
             e1.readonly="readonly";
             e1.name = 'sno';
             e1.value = iteration-1;
             e1.id = 'txtRow' + iteration;
             cell1.appendChild(e1);
             //another cell
            var cellRightSel = row.insertCell(1);
            var sel = document.createElement('select');
            sel.name = 'a_name[]';
            var rs=document.forms.form2.rws.value;
            var j=0;
            for(j=0;j<=rs;++j)
            {
            sel.options[j] = new Option(document.forms.form2.elements[j].value,document.forms.form2.elements[j].name);
            if(document.forms.form2.elements[j].value==a_name)
            {
            sel.options[j].selected=true;
            }
            }
            cellRightSel.appendChild(sel);
             var cell2 = row.insertCell(2);
             var e2 = document.createElement('input');
             //s=lastRow+1;
             e2.type = 'text';
             e2.size=4;
             e2.value=a_in;
             e2.name = 'a_in[]';
             e2.id = 'txtRow' + iteration;
             cell2.appendChild(e2);          
}
function removeRows()
{
  var tbl = document.getElementById('t');
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length;
  if (lastRow > 3) tbl.deleteRow(lastRow - 1);
}
function sbmt()
{
    frmco.action="";
    frmclose.submit();
}
</script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function Validate()
{
    if(""==document.form7.edleveid1.value)
    {
    alert("Select Education Level");
    document.form7.edleveid1.focus();
    return false;   
    }
    if(""==document.form7.tenure.value)
    {
    alert("Select currently tenure student belong to");
    document.form7.tenure.focus();
    return false;   
    }
else
{
window.location="results.php";
}
}

function Validate1()
{
    if(""==document.form7.classid.value)
    {
    alert("Select class where student joined");
    document.form7.classid.focus();
    return false;   
    }
else
{
window.location="results.php";
}
}
function Validate2()
{
    if(""==document.form7.examtype.value)
    {
    alert("Select exam type");
    document.form7.examtype.focus();
    return false;   
    }
    if(""==document.form7.subjectid.value)
    {
    alert("Select subject");
    document.form7.subjectid.focus();
    return false;   
    }
else
{
window.location="results.php";
}
}
</script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="accodation/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Datepicker/jquery-1.9.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Datepicker/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="Datepicker/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {color: #FF0000}
-->
</style>
</head>
<link href="css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div id="center-column">
            <div class="top-bar">
                <h1>Students</h1>
                <div class="breadcrumbs"><a href="#">Homepage</a> / <a href="#">Students</a></div>
            </div><br />
          <?php include('searchstudents.php'); ?>

          <div class="table">
         <form method="GET" name="form7" class="contentArea" id="form7" action="results.php">
                <img src="img/bg-th-left.gif" width="8" height="7" alt="" class="left" />
                <img src="img/bg-th-right.gif" width="7" height="7" alt="" class="right" />
                <table class="listing" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="tb" bgcolor="#D6D6D6">
                    <tr>
                        <th class="full" colspan="8">UPLOAD STUDENT'S RESULTS</th>
                    </tr>
                    <!--Start of default menu -->
                    <tr>
                        <td class="first" width="10"><strong>EdLevel</strong></td>
                        <td class="first" colspan="7">
                        <select name="edleveid1" id="edleveid1">
                        <option value="">Select Educational Level.....</option>
                          <?php 
              include("connect.php.inc");
             $sq11="select TEdlevelID,Name from streams where IsActive=1 and schoolID='".$_SESSION['schoolID']."' ";
             $rs11=mysql_query($sq11) or die(mysql_query());
             while($row11=mysql_fetch_array($rs11))
             {
              $TEdlevelID=$row11['TEdlevelID'];
                    $name=$row11['Name'];
            echo("<option value=\"".$TEdlevelID." \">".$name."</option>");
             }      
            ?> 
                        </select>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                        <select name="tenure" id="tenure">
                        <option value="">Select Current Student Tenure</option>
                        <option value="1">1 Yr</option>
                        <option value="2">2 Yrs</option>
                        <option value="3">3 Yrs</option>
                        <option value="4">4 Yrs</option>
                        <option value="5">5 Yrs</option>
                        </select>
                        <input type="submit" name="next1" value="Next" class="button" onclick="return Validate()" />

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <!--End of default input field selection -->
                    <!--start of selected details--> 
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_GET['next1']))
                    {
                    $TEdlevelID1=$_GET['edleveid1'];
                    $tenure=$_GET['tenure'];
                    ?>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="first" width="10"><strong>Class</strong></td>
                    <td class="first" colspan="7">
                    <select name="classid" id="classid">
                    <option value="">Select Class...</option>
                          <?php 
              include("connect.php.inc");
             $sq11="select c.ClassID,c.Name from streams s,classes c where s.IsActive=1 and c.IsActive=1 and s.TEdlevelID=c.EdTlevel and s.TEdlevelID='$TEdlevelID1' and s.SchoolID='".$_SESSION['schoolID']."' and c.schoolID='".$_SESSION['schoolID']."'";
             $rs11=mysql_query($sq11) or die(mysql_query());
             while($row11=mysql_fetch_array($rs11))
             {
              $ClassID=$row11['ClassID'];
              $name=$row11['Name'];
            echo("<option value=\"".$ClassID." \">".$name."</option>");
             }      
            ?>
                        </select>
                        <input type="hidden" name="eduIDnenda" value="<?php echo($TEdlevelID1);?>"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="mda" value="<?php echo($tenure);?>"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="next2" value="Next" class="button" onclick="return Validate1()"/><input type="submit" name="back" value="Back" class="button" />

                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                    <!--<--End start of selected details-->
                    <!--getting exam type -->

                    <?php
                    if(isset($_GET['next2']))
                    {
                    $classido=$_GET['classid'];
                    $edulevo=$_GET['eduIDnenda'];
                    $tenurep=$_GET['mda'];
                    ?>

                    <tr>
                    <td class="first" width="10"><strong>Exam Type</strong></td>
                    <td class="first" colspan="7">
                    <select name="examtype" id="examtype">
                    <option value="">Select Exam Type</option>
                          <?php 
              include("connect.php.inc");
             $sq11="select e.ExamID,e.Name from examtypescore e,classes s where e.IsActive=1 and s.IsActive=1 and e.ClassID=s.ClassID and s.SchoolID='".$_SESSION['schoolID']."' and e.schoolID='".$_SESSION['schoolID']."' and  e.ClassID='$classido'";
             $rs11=mysql_query($sq11) or die(mysql_query());
             while($row11=mysql_fetch_array($rs11))
             {
              $ExamID=$row11['ExamID'];
              $ainamtihani=$row11['Name'];
            echo("<option value=\"".$ExamID." \">".$ainamtihani."</option>");
             }      
            ?>
                        </select>
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Subject</strong>
                        <select name="subjectid" id="subjectid">
                    <option value="">Select Subject</option>
                          <?php 
              include("connect.php.inc");
             $sq11="select s.SubjectName,s.SubjectID from subjects s,streams se  where s.SchoolID='".$_SESSION['schoolID']."' and se.schoolID='".$_SESSION['schoolID']."' and  s.TEdLevelID='$edulevo' and s.TEdLevelID=se.TEdLevelID";
             $rs11=mysql_query($sq11) or die(mysql_query());
             while($row11=mysql_fetch_array($rs11))
             {
              $SubjectID=$row11['SubjectID'];
              $SubjectName=$row11['SubjectName'];
            echo("<option value=\"".$SubjectID." \">".$SubjectName."</option>");
             }      
            ?>
                        </select>
                        <input type="hidden" name="classidnenda" value="<?php echo($classido);?>"/><input type="hidden" name="elimu" value="<?php echo($edulevo);?>"/><input type="hidden" name="somo" value="<?php echo($SubjectName);?>"/><input type="hidden" name="aina" value="<?php echo($ExamID);?>"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="mdaa" value="<?php echo($tenurep);?>"/>
                        <input type="submit" name="next3" value="Start" class="button" onclick="return Validate2()"/><input type="submit" name="back" value="Back" class="button" />

                    </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                    <!--end getting exam type -->
                    </form>
                    <form method="GET" name="form1" class="contentArea" id="form1" action="results5.php">
                    <!-- starting input data   -->
                    <?php
                    if(isset($_GET['next3']))
                    {
                    $classid=$_GET['classidnenda'];
                    $elimulevo=$_GET['elimu'];
                    $examid=$_GET['aina'];
                    $somo=$_GET['subjectid'];
                    $tenure1=$_GET['mdaa'];
                    //$mdakamili=RIGHT($tenure1,1);
            $sq113="select Name from streams where IsActive=1 and schoolID='".$_SESSION['schoolID']."' and TEdlevelID='$elimulevo'";
             $rs113=mysql_query($sq113) or die(mysql_query());
             while($row113=mysql_fetch_array($rs113))
             {
              $a=$row113['Name'];
             }

             $sq1131="select Name from examtypescore where IsActive=1 and schoolID='".$_SESSION['schoolID']."' and ExamID='$examid'";
             $rs1131=mysql_query($sq1131) or die(mysql_query());
             while($row1131=mysql_fetch_array($rs1131))
             {
              $c=$row1131['Name'];
             }

             $sq11312="select Name from classes where IsActive=1 and schoolID='".$_SESSION['schoolID']."' and ClassID='$classid'";
             $rs11312=mysql_query($sq11312) or die(mysql_query());
             while($row11312=mysql_fetch_array($rs11312))
             {
              $b=$row11312['Name'];
             }

             $sq11312="select SubjectName from subjects where IsActive=1 and schoolID='".$_SESSION['schoolID']."' and SubjectID='$somo'";
             $rs11312=mysql_query($sq11312) or die(mysql_query());
             while($row11312=mysql_fetch_array($rs11312))
             {
              $d=$row11312['SubjectName'];
             }
                    ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td class="first" width="10"><strong>EdLevel</strong></td>
                        <td class="first" ><?php echo($a);?><input type="hidden" class="text" size="10"  name="elimuyake"value="<?php echo($elimulevo);?>"/></td>
                        <td class="first" width="10"><strong>Class</strong></td>
                        <td class="first" ><?php echo($b);?>&nbsp;yrs:(<?php echo($tenure1); ?>)<input type="hidden" class="text"  name="darasa"size="10" value="<?php echo($classid);?>" /></td>
                        <td class="first" width="10"><strong>ExamType</strong></td>
                        <td class="first" ><?php echo($c);?><input type="hidden" class="text" size="10"  name="ainamtihani"value="<?php echo($examid);?>" /></td>
                        <td class="first" width="10"><strong>Subject</strong></td>
                        <td class="first" ><?php echo($d);?><input type="hidden" name="somolake" class="text" size="10" value="<?php echo($somo);?>" /></td>
                    </tr>
           </table> 
<table class="listing" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" id="t" bgcolor="#D6D6D6">
                        <td class="first" width="10">
                        <input type="text" name="sn" value="1" readonly="" size="1" /></td>

                        <td class="first" colspan="3">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <select name="a_name" id="a_name">
                <option value=""></option>
             <?php 
              include("connect.php.inc");
              $sql="SELECT s.Lname, s.Mname, s.Fname, s.studentID,s.ey,s.sy, s.ClassID, RIGHT( s.ey - s.sy, 1 ) AS yrs, str.tenure, s.schoolID, cl.EdTlevel, s.IsActive, cl.ClassID
FROM students s, streams str, classes cl
GROUP BY s.StudentID
HAVING s.schoolID ='".$_SESSION['schoolID']."'
AND s.ClassID ='$classid' and s.IsActive=1 and RIGHT( s.ey - s.sy, 1 )='$tenure1'";
$resultsx=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 while($row11=mysql_fetch_array($resultsx))
             {
              $studentID=$row11['studentID'];
              $ClassID=$row11['ClassID'];
              $yrs=$row11['yrs'];
              $Fname=$row11['Fname'];
              $Mname=$row11['Mname'];
              $Lname=$row11['Lname'];
              echo("<option value=\"".$studentID." \">".$Fname.' '.$Mname.' '.$Lname."</option>");
             }

            ?>
            </select>     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<strong>Marks</strong>
                        <input type="text" class="text"  name="a_in"  size="4"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                    <td class="first" colspan="4" align="right">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                 <input name="Submit2" type="reset" class="button" id="Submit2" value="RESET">
                 <input name="Submit3" type="button" class="button" id="Submit3" value="ADD ROW" onClick="addRows()">
                 <input name="Submit4" type="button" class="button" id="Submit4" value="DELETE ROW" onClick="removeRows()">
                 <input name="save" type="submit" class="button" id="save" value="SAVE">
                 </td>
                 </tr>
             <?php
            }
            ?>
                 </table>
          </div>
  </form>
<form name="form2" class="contentArea">     
      <?php 
      if(isset($_GET['next3']))
                    {
      error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
              include("connect.php.inc");
             $sq11="SELECT s.Lname, s.Mname, s.Fname, s.ey,s.sy,s.studentID, s.ClassID, RIGHT( s.ey - s.sy, 1 ) AS yrs, str.tenure, s.schoolID, cl.EdTlevel, s.IsActive, cl.ClassID
FROM students s, streams str, classes cl
GROUP BY s.StudentID
HAVING s.schoolID ='".$_SESSION['schoolID']."'
AND s.ClassID ='$classid' and s.IsActive=1 and RIGHT( s.ey - s.sy, 1 )='$tenure1'";
$resultsx=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
 while($row11=mysql_fetch_array($resultsx))
             {
              $studentID=$row11['studentID'];
              $ClassID=$row11['ClassID'];
              $yrs=$row11['yrs'];
              $Fname=$row11['Fname'];
              $Mname=$row11['Mname'];
              $Lname=$row11['Lname'];
                 echo("<input name='$StudentID'\" type=\"hidden\" value='$Fname $Mname $Lname'\">");
             ++$n;
             }  
             ?>
          <input name="rws" type="hidden" id="rws" value="<?php echo($n);?>">
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
results5.php
<?php
if(isset($_GET['save']))
     {
     error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
     $somolake=$_GET['somolake'];
     $darasa=$_GET['darasa'];
     $elimuyake=$_GET['elimuyake'];
     $ainamtihani=$_GET['ainamtihani'];
     $jina=$_GET['a_name'];
    include("connect.php.inc");
    foreach($_GET['a_name'] as $row=>$name)
    {
     //$jina=mysql_real_escape_string($name);
    $jina=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['a_name'][$row]);
    //$jina=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['a_name'][$row]);
     $alama=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['a_in'][$row]);
    //$alama=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['a_in']);
     $sq2="insert into results(StudentID,SubjectID,ClassID,ExamID,Marks,SchoolID,PostedBy)
      value ('$jina','$somolake','$darasa','$ainamtihani','$alama','".$_SESSION['schoolID']."','".$_SESSION['userid']."')";
     mysql_query($sq2) or die(mysql_error());
}
include("success.php");
     }
```

Comment: Are you sure `$_GET['a_name']` is an array or an object?

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore, they are deprecated. See [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) for details. Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: @putvande Usually `$_GET['a_name']` is neither, but a string.

Comment: thanks Marcel for your advise

Comment: $_GET['a_name'] is an object but it's array on the javascript      var sel = document.createElement('select');
            sel.name = 'a_name[]';

Answer (score 0):

You can always check whether your variable is an array or not before supplying it to foreach.Try doing this:

```
if(is_array($item))
{
 foreach($item as $items)
 {
    //your code
 }
}
```

Comment: sel.name = 'a_name[]'; on the javascript is an array but we should get this as object.